# What causes failure to compile SASS in this svelte applcation?

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I am working on a project with Svelte and the material design library **[Svelte Material UI](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui)**.

This material design library requires SASS, so I installed a preprocessor with `npm install svelte-preprocess` and added `preprocess: autoPreprocess()` in rollup.config.js. So I now have:

```
plugins: [
    svelte({
        // enable run-time checks when not in production
        dev: !production,
        // we'll extract any component CSS out into
        // a separate file - better for performance
        css: css => {
            css.write('public/build/bundle.css');
        },
        preprocess: autoPreprocess()
    }),
    routify({ singleBuild : true}),
    replace({
      // stringify the object
      APPENV: JSON.stringify({         
          isProd: production,
          ...config().parsed // attached the .env config            
      }),
  }),
  // more stuff
]
```

I have a file `smui.js` with this content:

```
import Button from '@smui/button';
import Checkbox from '@smui/checkbox';
import Chips from '@smui/chips';
import Dialog from '@smui/dialog';
import FormField from '@smui/form-field';
import Select from '@smui/select';

export {
  Button,
  Checkbox,
  Chips,
  Dialog,
  FormField,
  Select
}
```

In my `index.svelt`e file I am importing the above this way: `import * as Smui from "../smui.js";`.

Instead of a success message with the port on which the app should run, I get:

```
[!] Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
node_modules\@smui\dialog\_index.scss (1:0)
1: @import "smui-theme";
   ^
2: @import "./style";
Error: Unexpected character '@' (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you including the sass in your Svelte component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used @import to import components from a NPM package, but at the readme package you're referencing it recommends using 'import x from" svelte-material'. Also pay attention that svelte-preprocess won't be supported by the package you're referencing, take a look at the readme:

To bundle this in your own code, use a Sass processor (not a Sass Svelte preprocessor, but a Sass processor).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and somehow I managed to fix this with `rollup-plugin-postcss` plugin. Update your `rollup.config.js` with the following code and you should have `_smui-theme.scss` in your one of sass directories.

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
...

plugins: [
        svelte({
            // enable run-time checks when not in production
            dev: !production,
            // we'll extract any component CSS out into
            // a separate file - better for performance
            css: css => {
                css.write('public/build/bundle.css')
            }
        }),

        postcss({
            extensions: ['.css'],
            extract: true,
            minimize: true,
            use: [['sass', { includePaths: ['./src/(yoursass-directory-name)', './node_modules'] }]]
        })
```

Comment: With this configuration change, I'm getting one more problem. Component CSS and other CSS styles are not applying. I think this plugin overriding the CSS but I'm not sure